# Messages from ActiveMQ Artemis topic are not delivered to all the subscribed MDBs

Tags: jboss, activemq-artemis

Here is our set up with 3 JBoss 7.1.6 instances:

- Rest JBoss instance: notifies MDB on vendor instance by inserting a message to a topic.
- JMS instance: hosts the JMS topic.
- Vendor instance: hosts 3 MDBs that listen to the topic with same message selection criteria.

After inserting below message to ActiveMQ Artemis topic named "life cycle" the messages are not consistently delivered to all 3 subscribers (MDBs).

JMS message:

```
{"id":"10774830","type":"x.y.z.domains.Order","changeList":[{"propertyName":"isReadyForSO","oldValue":false,"newValue":true}]} for action type UPDATE
```

Vendor instance has 3 Message Driven Beans subscribed to `lifecycle` topic.

Below are activation config properties for each MDB:

MDB1:

```java
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
@MessageDriven(activationConfig = {
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Topic"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destination", propertyValue = "jms/topic/lifecycle"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "messageSelector", propertyValue =
                "(action='UPDATE' AND 
                        type ='x.y.z.domains.Order')"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "subscriptionDurability", propertyValue = "Durable"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "clientId", propertyValue = "MDB1"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "subscriptionName", propertyValue = "OrderStateChange"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "maxSession", propertyValue = "10")
})
```

MDB2:

```java
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED)
@MessageDriven(activationConfig = {
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Topic"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destination", propertyValue = "jms/topic/lifecycle"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "messageSelector", propertyValue =
                "(action='UPDATE' AND 
                        type ='x.y.z.domains.Order')"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "subscriptionDurability", propertyValue = "Durable"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "clientId", propertyValue = "MDB2"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "subscriptionName", propertyValue = "OrderStateChange"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "maxSession", propertyValue = "10")
})
```

MDB3:

```java
@MessageDriven(activationConfig = {
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Topic"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destination", propertyValue = "jms/topic/lifecycle"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "messageSelector", propertyValue =
                "(action='UPDATE' AND 
                        type ='x.y.z.domains.Order')"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "maxSession", propertyValue = "1")
})
```

The messages are not consistently delivered to all 3 MDBs all the time. Sometimes it is only delivered to 1 MDB that is randomly picked and Sometimes it is delivered to all MDBs.

I scanned through logs to see if there are any errors, nothing.
All the MDBs have the same message selection criteria. In any case, shouldn't all MDBs receive the message all the time?

Comment: Does the behavior change if you just have 1 MDB? What about just 2? Does the behavior change if you simplify the environment, for example if the MDBs are running on the same instance as the JMS broker? The simpler the environment is the easier it will be to diagnose the issue.

Comment: It is still inconsistent even after, if  i cut down to 2. I was able to intermittently  reproduce this locally, where all are running on same instance.

Comment: Does @TransactionAttribute matter on each MDB ? one has : @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED)
. The other two has : @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)

Comment: I wouldn't expect any `@TransactionAttribute` value to prevent message delivery to the MDB. It's important to simplify the use-case as much as possible. Once you get that done then you can create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Justin i am close to completing a reprex example. My example will put a message on a topic and i will configure 3 MDB's as subscribers. While i am thinking how to confirm if a particular message dropped on to a topic is actually received by 3 subscribers in my example. Do you know a better way to confirm this ?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking. I can't really comment on the best way to confirm the problem since I don't know what the underlying problem actually is. In terms of the minimal reproducible example the best way to design it is to make sure it's as simple as possible. For example, you may not even need MDBs. The problem may be reproducible with just normal JMS topic subscribers. If so, that would be quite a bit simpler as it would eliminate the entire EJB and JCA subsystems from the equation.

Comment: @JustinBertam : sorry i took so long to get back,  https://github.com/rohithreddy41/reprex-simple.git is the simplest example i could reproduce with just 1 subscriber to the topic and the subscirber is not able to receive any messages from the topic. I have added more notes under : moreInfo/readme . Just FYI, i was able to reproduce the problem by bringing in MDB/JCA into picture.

Comment: There's at least 2 problems with your reproducer. First, you send the message before the subscriber is created which means the subscriber won't get the messages. When the messages are sent there are no subscriptions so the messages will simply be discarded. This is normal pub/sub semantics. Your second problem is that you're not calling [`start()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/Connection.html#start--) on the JMS connection in your `MessageManagerBean` therefore messages will never flow to the `TopicSubscriber`.

Comment: Since it is running in the JBOSS i thought i do not have to call start on connection.(i could be missing something) . I made changes like you suggested, but i still do not see any messages in the receive method. Updated the log on git.

Comment: Your Maven project won't build. I get this: `Non-resolvable import POM: Could not find artifact org.jboss.bom:jboss-eap-javaee7:pom:7.1.6.GA in central`.

Comment: its there : https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.bom/jboss-eap-javaee7/7.1.6.GA .

Comment: Your link says that artifact is in the "Redhat EA" repository. I don't have that repository in my Maven `settings.xml` and most others users probably don't as well. Furthermore, there are no instructions in your reproducer about adding this repository. You should assume that users only have the default repository (i.e. Maven Central - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2). Also, do I need Red Hat EAP to run this test? If so, where should I get it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217268/discussion-between-rohith-and-justin-bertram).